# How to display icon in mat-table row?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I use the mat-table and return an html data (an hyperlink) to this table and want to display icon or html on the related column's rows.

```
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></tr>
```

But I am not sure how can I display it and how to distinguist if the related column is icon column. Because I do not get `tableColumn` peoperty in the row. How can I do this?

Here is a [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/angular/ngplgdbmbje?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-basic-example.ts) and in this demo I just want to render this hyperlink below:

```
const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
  {position: 1, 
      name: '<a href="http://www.google.com/search?q=Angular">Angular</a>', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H'},
  {position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He'}
];
```

Comment: an illustration of what you are trying to achieve would help to answer this question

Comment: Sorry, I added update.

Comment: @SupunDeSilva Could you have opportunity to have a look at the demo?

Comment: I think @Arunkumar Ramasamy answered the question. seem to do the job I believe.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `mat-icon` in your `mat-cell` and assign your html data to `innerHTML` attribute.

```
<!-- Name Column -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="name">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> 
    <mat-icon [innerHTML]="element.name"></mat-icon> </td>
</ng-container>
```

Reference: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8vpb5f?file=src/app/table-basic-example.html